# Apply for a Vistor VISA UK

Tags: visas, uk, student-visas

I have a student visa that will expire January 30
But I also have a conference I'm invited to give an oral presentation at in February

So I was told I need to apply for a standard visitor visa 
Is this possible to do from inside the uk?

Answer (score 1):

No. You must apply online from outside the UK https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/apply